# name collision in input Nix expressions with nix-env -f

Tags: nixos, nix

Following [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40541284/3335288) that was given to me, I started following the nixpkgs-unstable channel with a git clone of this repository: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/

My clone is in `~/nixpkgs`. I'm calling `nix-shell` with option `-I ~` and it works fine. For `nix-env` the `-I` option does not exist but I understand that one should instead use the `-f` option. So far (on two different machines) I did just that (calling `nix-env` with option `-f ~`) and it worked fine.

Now, I'm on a third machine and I tried to reproduce the same process. I tried to install a package which is in nixpkgs-unstable but not on my system channel nixos-16.09 with the command `nix-env -f ~ -iA nixpkgs.exercism` but it fails with the following error message:

```
warning: name collision in input Nix expressions, skipping ‘/home/theo/nixpkgs’
error: attribute ‘exercism’ in selection path ‘nixpkgs.exercism’ not found
```

Searching for this error message gave me this http://lists.science.uu.nl/pipermail/nix-dev/2013-October/011898.html
but I'm not in the situation described. I am not following any channel as a normal user (`nix-channel --list` answer is empty) and my only system-wide channel is called nixos (further confirmed by the fact that `.nix-defexpr/` only contains `channels_root/` which in turn contains `binary-caches`, `manifest.nix` and `nixos`).

What did I do wrong?

To note: I can fix my problem by issuing instead the command `nix-env -f ~/nixpkgs -iA exercism` but I still would really like to understand why my first solution did not work (even if it did work on two other machines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/215b70f51e5abd350c9b7db656aedac9d96d0046/src/nix-env/nix-env.cc#L127) it seems very likely you have another `nixpkgs` directory somewhere in `~`.

`nix-env` searches (recursively) all directories for `default.nix` adding the parent directory as a top level attribute.

Using `nix-env -f ~` seems like a bad idea - very much to search and chances for such collisions. Unless there's something I'm missing symlinking `~/nixpkgs` into `~/.nix-defexpr` seems like a good solution.

There's nothing wrong with simply using `nix-env -f nixpkgs -iA exercism`. In this form nix sees a `default.nix` directly in the `-f` argument and uses that as the top level attribute set.

If you can't find another nixpkgs directory, I'd try using the `--show-trace` option.

Comment: Thanks! You allowed me to understand at the same time why the commands `nix-env -f ~` and `nix-shell -I ~` were so slow at start-up. I will avoid using these in favor of `nix-env -f ~/nixpkgs` and `nix-shell -I nixpkgs=~/nixpkgs` now.